# Print from A4 to A0

Tags: formatting, printing

I am a math teacher and am working on a brochure for my students, but I'm doing this aquivo in A0 size, how can I do to change to A4 without unconfigure the page.
Excuse my lack of knowledge in Latex.

```
 \documentclass{sciposter}
\usepackage{preposterTikz} %pacote com o preambulo.

%%comandos exclusivos deste poster.
\hypersetup{pdfpagelayout=SinglePage,linkcolor=true} %abre a pagina em modo simples
\geometry{paperwidth=90cm,paperheight=100cm,centering,
    textwidth=77cm,textheight=87cm,left=4cm,top=4cm}
%********************************************************************
\begin{document}

%%Preencha os comandos abaixo com seus dados.
\newcommand{\tituloposter}{Poster Cient\'ifico no {\LaTeX} com TikZ} %%titulo do poster
\newcommand{\nome}{Fulano de Tal} %%seu nome
\newcommand{\curso}{Acad\^emico do Curso de Ci\^encias} %%curso
\newcommand{\myemail}{email@email.com} %%email
\newcommand{\nomecongresso}{1$^\circ$ Congresso Nacional de Inicia\c{c}\~ao Cient\' ifica} %%congresso
\newcommand{\abrev}{I CNIC} %%abrevia\c c\~ao

%%Imagem de fundo (background)
\imgfundo{abstract_0079}

%%titulo feito com TikZ (usando \newcommand).
%%informe o primeiro e segundo logo e a cor.
\titulo{logo}{sbm_simb}{twoblue}
%\titulo{logo}{sbm_simb}{OrangeLampLight}

%%informe a cor.
%\congresso{GreenTeal}

\vspace{5cm} %espa\c{c}o

%%informe o terceiro e quarto logo e a cor.
\rodape{logo_redebrasil}{cnpq}{twoblue}
%\rodape{logo_redebrasil}{cnpq}{OrangeLampLight}

%%Definindo largura para as caixas.
\newdimen\largura
\largura=.3\textwidth
%%Estilos
\tikzstyle{mybox}=[draw=blue,fill=yellow!20,very thick,
    rectangle,rounded corners=5mm,inner sep=10mm]
\tikzstyle{subtitulo}=[fill=twoblue,text=white,yshift=5mm,inner sep=10pt]

%%Primeira caixa
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.05*\textwidth]%,opacity=.75] %%se quiser voce pode usar uma transpar\^encia.

\node[mybox] (box1) {
    \begin{minipage}[t][20cm]{\largura}
      %%Paragrafo.
      \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
      %%digite seu texto aqui
      \begin{center}
      \textbf{Progressão Aritmética (PA)}
      \end{center}

Fórmula do termo geral de uma PA

$$a_n = a_1 +(n-1)r$$

Soma dos $n$ primeiros termos de uma PA

$$S_n = \displaystyle \frac{(a_1 + a_n)n}{2}$$

\begin{center}
\textbf{Progressão Geométrica (PG)}
\end{center}

Fórmula do termo geral de uma PG

$$a_n = a_1 \times q^{n-1}$$

Soma dos $n$ primeiros termos de uma PG

$$S_n =\displaystyle \frac{a_1(q^n -1)}{q-1}$$ 


    \end{minipage}
    };
%%digite o subtitulo aqui.
\node[subtitulo,minimum width=\largura] at (box1.north) {\tituloA{Progressões}};



%%Segunda caixa
%%Definindo nova largura.
\largura=.3\textwidth
\node[mybox] (box2) [right = of box1.north east,anchor=north west] {
    \begin{minipage}[t][20cm]{\largura}

      %%Paragrafo.
      \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
      %%digite seu texto aqui
      \indent Definição:\\
\begin{center}
$\log_b a = x \Leftrightarrow a= b^x$, com $a > 0$ e $0< b \neq 1$
\end{center}


Propriedades:

\begin{enumerate}
\item[1.]$\log_c (a.b) = \log_c a + \log_c b$ com $a>0, b>0, 0<c\neq1$
\item[2.]$\log_c \displaystyle{\frac{a}{b}} = \log_c a - \log_c b$ com $a>0, b>0, 0<c\neq1$
\item[3.]$\log_c a^m = m\log_c a$ com $a>0$, $0<c\neq 1$, $m \in \mathbb{R}$
\end{enumerate}


    \end{minipage}
    };
%%digite o subtitulo aqui.
\node[subtitulo,minimum width=\largura] at (box2.north) {\tituloA{Logaritmo}};


\largura=.3\textwidth
\node[mybox] (box6) [right = of box2.north east,anchor=north west] {
    \begin{minipage}[t][20cm]{\largura}

      %%Paragrafo.
      \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
      %%digite seu texto aqui
      \indent Relações Métricas no Triângulo Retângulo:\\

\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  %\input{figuras/figtikz}\\
  \includegraphics[scale=1.3]{ab.png}
\end{figure}

$$h^2 = m\cdot n$$
$$b^2 = a\cdot m$$
$$c^2 = a\cdot n$$
$$b\cdot c = a\cdot h$$
\begin{center}
$a^2 = b^2 + c^2$ (Pitágoras)
\end{center}

 \end{minipage}
    };
%%digite o subtitulo aqui.
\node[subtitulo,minimum width=\largura] at (box6.north) {\tituloA{Logaritmo}};





%%Terceira caixa
\node[mybox] (box3) [below = of box1.south west,anchor=north west] {
    \begin{minipage}[t][16cm]{\largura}
      %%Paragrafo.
      \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
      %%digite seu texto aqui
      \indent Função injetora, sobrejetora e bijetora
\begin{enumerate}
\item[•] Uma função $f: A \rightarrow B$ é injetora se todos os elementos distintos em A têm imagens distintas em B.
\item[•] Uma função $f:A \rightarrow B$ é sobrejetora se todos os elementos de B são imagens de elementos de A.
\item[•] Uma função $f: A \rightarrow B$ é bijetora se é injetora e sobrejetora.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{fcinj.png}
\end{figure}

    \end{minipage}
    };
%%digite o subtitulo aqui.
\node[subtitulo,minimum width=\largura] at (box3.north) {\tituloA{Figuras TikZ}};


\largura=.3\textwidth
\node[mybox] (box7) [below = of box3.south west,anchor=north west] {
    \begin{minipage}[t][16cm]{\largura}

      %%Paragrafo.
      \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
      %%digite seu texto aqui
      \indent \begin{enumerate}
\item[•] Combinação: $\displaystyle C_{n,p} = \frac{n!}{p!(n-p)!}$
\item[•] Arranjo: $\displaystyle A_{n,p} = \frac{n!}{(n-p)!} $
\item[•] Permutação de $n$ objetos distintos: $P_n = n!$
\item[•] Permutação de elementos repetidos: $P_{n}^{\alpha,\beta,\gamma} = \displaystyle\frac{n!}{\alpha ! \beta! \gamma !}$
\item[•] Probabilidade de ocorrer um evento $\displaystyle = \frac{n(A)}{n(E)}$

\end{enumerate}

 \end{minipage}
    };
%%digite o subtitulo aqui.
\node[subtitulo,minimum width=\largura] at (box7.north) {\tituloA{Análise Combinatória}};







%%Quarta caixa
%%Definindo nova largura. 
\largura=.3\textwidth
\node[mybox] (box4) [right = of box3.north east,anchor=north west] {
    \begin{minipage}[t][16cm]{\largura}
      %%Paragrafo.
      \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
      %%digite seu texto aqui
      \indent Razões Trigonométricas no Triângulo Retângulo :\\

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.3]{ba.png}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
$sen (\alpha) = \displaystyle{\frac{b}{a}}$ \hspace{4cm} $sen (\beta) = \displaystyle{\frac{c}{a}}$
\end{center}
\begin{center}
$cos (\alpha) = \displaystyle{\frac{c}{a}}$ \hspace{4cm}  $cos (\beta) = \displaystyle{\frac{b}{a}}$
\end{center}
\begin{center}
$tg (\alpha) = \displaystyle{\frac{b}{c}}$ \hspace{4cm}  $cos (\beta) = \displaystyle{\frac{c}{b}}$

\end{center}



    \end{minipage}
    };
%%digite o subtitulo aqui.
\node[subtitulo,minimum width=\largura] at (box4.north) {\tituloA{Conclus\~ao}};

%%Quinta caixa
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}
\node[mybox] (box5) [below = of box4.south west,anchor=north west] {
    \begin{minipage}[t][17cm]{\largura}
      Área e Comprimento da Circunferência:\\

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=1.7]{abc.png}
\end{figure} 

$$C = 2\cdot \pi \cdot R$$
$$A = \pi \cdot R^2$$

    \end{minipage}
    };
%%digite o subtitulo aqui.
\node[subtitulo,minimum width=\largura] at (box5.north) {\tituloA{Refer\^encias}};
\endgroup
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want just a scaled version is better to print it in pdf file using pdf printer and choose to fit to printed area.

Comment: I tried that but it did not work.But thank you for your attention. @Sigur

Comment: @Henfe -- I assume you want to change an AO size output into an A4 size output and then print it. If this is the case. You could use package "pdfpages" and "\includepdf[turn=false,pages=1]{YourAoPoster.pdf}" to convert AO pdf into A4 pdf format.

Answer (score 1):

We could extract portions/cells of the PDF file automatically (A4 pages out of the PDF file in this example), but this is not the case as blocks have different size. I was thinking if [`fancytooltips`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips) could be used as there is an extraction process written in Perl, but we would need to properly wrap the blocks. It wouldn't be easy as `\node`s need its `tikzpicture` environment, but it could be done, I guess. My next idea was to implement `external` library from the [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) package somehow, probably with help of the [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) package (`\pause` command).

In this answer I have done semi-automatic extraction. When we cut down the code a little we are getting the poster. I roughly measured rectangles of poster and I used `viewport` and `clip` parameters from the [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package to extract them.
The parts consist a new PDF file which is cropped afterwards. I enclose compilable version of the poster, TeX code of the extraction and a preview of those 7 parts/pages.

After this job is done we can load pages back where and as we need them. I would use [`pdfpages`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package for such a task. I run following two lines with `lualatex`, but `xelatex` and `lualatex` can be used.

> lualatex mal-poster.tex
>   lualatex mal-poster-extraction.tex
>   pdfcrop --hires mal-poster-extraction.pdf

The content of the `mal-poster.tex` file is this:

```
%! *latex mal-poster.tex
\documentclass{sciposter}
%\usepackage{preposterTikz} %pacote com o preambulo.
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\colorlet{twoblue}{blue}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\def\tituloA#1{\large #1}
%%comandos exclusivos deste poster.
\hypersetup{pdfpagelayout=SinglePage,linkcolor=true} %abre a pagina em modo simples
\geometry{paperwidth=90cm,paperheight=100cm,centering,
    textwidth=77cm,textheight=87cm,left=4cm,top=4cm}
%********************************************************************
\begin{document}
%%Preencha os comandos abaixo com seus dados.
\newcommand{\tituloposter}{Poster Cient\'ifico no {\LaTeX} com TikZ} %%titulo do poster
\newcommand{\nome}{Fulano de Tal} %%seu nome
\newcommand{\curso}{Acad\^emico do Curso de Ci\^encias} %%curso
\newcommand{\myemail}{email@email.com} %%email
\newcommand{\nomecongresso}{1$^\circ$ Congresso Nacional de Inicia\c{c}\~ao Cient\' ifica} %%congresso
\newcommand{\abrev}{I CNIC} %%abrevia\c c\~ao
%%Imagem de fundo (background)
%\imgfundo{abstract_0079}
%%titulo feito com TikZ (usando \newcommand).
%%informe o primeiro e segundo logo e a cor.
%\titulo{logo}{sbm_simb}{twoblue}
%\titulo{logo}{sbm_simb}{OrangeLampLight}
%%informe a cor.
%\congresso{GreenTeal}
\vspace{5cm} %espa\c{c}o
%%informe o terceiro e quarto logo e a cor.
%\rodape{logo_redebrasil}{cnpq}{twoblue}
%\rodape{logo_redebrasil}{cnpq}{OrangeLampLight}
%%Definindo largura para as caixas.
\newdimen\largura
\largura=.3\textwidth
%%Estilos
\tikzstyle{mybox}=[draw=blue,fill=yellow!20,very thick,
    rectangle,rounded corners=5mm,inner sep=10mm]
\tikzstyle{subtitulo}=[fill=twoblue,text=white,yshift=5mm,inner sep=10pt]

%%Primeira caixa
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=.05*\textwidth]%,opacity=.75] %%se quiser voce pode usar uma transpar\^encia.

\node[mybox] (box1) {
    \begin{minipage}[t][20cm]{\largura}
      %%Paragrafo.
      \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
      %%digite seu texto aqui
      \begin{center}
      \textbf{Progressão Aritmética (PA)}
      \end{center}

Fórmula do termo geral de uma PA

$$a_n = a_1 +(n-1)r$$

Soma dos $n$ primeiros termos de uma PA

$$S_n = \displaystyle \frac{(a_1 + a_n)n}{2}$$

\begin{center}
\textbf{Progressão Geométrica (PG)}
\end{center}

Fórmula do termo geral de uma PG

$$a_n = a_1 \times q^{n-1}$$

Soma dos $n$ primeiros termos de uma PG

$$S_n =\displaystyle \frac{a_1(q^n -1)}{q-1}$$ 
    \end{minipage}
    };
%%digite o subtitulo aqui.
\node[subtitulo,minimum width=5cm] at (box1.north) {Progressões};

%%Segunda caixa
%%Definindo nova largura.
\largura=.3\textwidth
\node[mybox] (box2) [right = of box1.north east,anchor=north west] {
    \begin{minipage}[t][20cm]{\largura}
      %%Paragrafo.
      \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
      %%digite seu texto aqui
      \indent Definição:\\
\begin{center}
$\log_b a = x \Leftrightarrow a= b^x$, com $a > 0$ e $0< b \neq 1$
\end{center}
Propriedades:
\begin{enumerate}
\item[1.]$\log_c (a.b) = \log_c a + \log_c b$ com $a>0, b>0, 0<c\neq1$
\item[2.]$\log_c \displaystyle{\frac{a}{b}} = \log_c a - \log_c b$ com $a>0, b>0, 0<c\neq1$
\item[3.]$\log_c a^m = m\log_c a$ com $a>0$, $0<c\neq 1$, $m \in \mathbb{R}$
\end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
    };
%%digite o subtitulo aqui.

\node[subtitulo,minimum width=\largura] at (box2.north) {\tituloA{Logaritmo}};
\largura=.3\textwidth
\node[mybox] (box6) [right = of box2.north east,anchor=north west] {
    \begin{minipage}[t][20cm]{\largura}
      %%Paragrafo.
      \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
      %%digite seu texto aqui
      \indent Relações Métricas no Triângulo Retângulo:\\
\begin{figure}[!h]
  \centering
  %\input{figuras/figtikz}\\
  %\includegraphics[scale=1.3]{ab.png}
\end{figure}
$$h^2 = m\cdot n$$
$$b^2 = a\cdot m$$
$$c^2 = a\cdot n$$
$$b\cdot c = a\cdot h$$
\begin{center}
$a^2 = b^2 + c^2$ (Pitágoras)
\end{center}
 \end{minipage}
    };
%%digite o subtitulo aqui.
\node[subtitulo,minimum width=\largura] at (box6.north) {\tituloA{Logaritmo}};
%%Terceira caixa
\node[mybox] (box3) [below = of box1.south west,anchor=north west] {
    \begin{minipage}[t][16cm]{\largura}
      %%Paragrafo.
      \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
      %%digite seu texto aqui
      \indent Função injetora, sobrejetora e bijetora
\begin{enumerate}
\item[•] Uma função $f: A \rightarrow B$ é injetora se todos os elementos distintos em A têm imagens distintas em B.
\item[•] Uma função $f:A \rightarrow B$ é sobrejetora se todos os elementos de B são imagens de elementos de A.
\item[•] Uma função $f: A \rightarrow B$ é bijetora se é injetora e sobrejetora.
\end{enumerate}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
%\includegraphics[scale=1.0]{fcinj.png}
\end{figure}
    \end{minipage}
    };
%%digite o subtitulo aqui.
\node[subtitulo,minimum width=\largura] at (box3.north) {\tituloA{Figuras TikZ}};

\largura=.3\textwidth
\node[mybox] (box7) [below = of box3.south west,anchor=north west] {
    \begin{minipage}[t][16cm]{\largura}
      %%Paragrafo.
      \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
      %%digite seu texto aqui
      \indent \begin{enumerate}
\item[•] Combinação: $\displaystyle C_{n,p} = \frac{n!}{p!(n-p)!}$
\item[•] Arranjo: $\displaystyle A_{n,p} = \frac{n!}{(n-p)!} $
\item[•] Permutação de $n$ objetos distintos: $P_n = n!$
\item[•] Permutação de elementos repetidos: $P_{n}^{\alpha,\beta,\gamma} = \displaystyle\frac{n!}{\alpha ! \beta! \gamma !}$
\item[•] Probabilidade de ocorrer um evento $\displaystyle = \frac{n(A)}{n(E)}$
\end{enumerate}
 \end{minipage}
    };
%%digite o subtitulo aqui.
\node[subtitulo,minimum width=\largura] at (box7.north) {\tituloA{Análise Combinatória}};
%%Quarta caixa
%%Definindo nova largura. 
\largura=.3\textwidth
\node[mybox] (box4) [right = of box3.north east,anchor=north west] {
    \begin{minipage}[t][16cm]{\largura}
      %%Paragrafo.
      \setlength{\parindent}{2em}
      %%digite seu texto aqui
      \indent Razões Trigonométricas no Triângulo Retângulo :\\
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
%\includegraphics[scale=1.3]{ba.png}
\end{figure}
\begin{center}
$sen (\alpha) = \displaystyle{\frac{b}{a}}$ \hspace{4cm} $sen (\beta) = \displaystyle{\frac{c}{a}}$
\end{center}
\begin{center}
$cos (\alpha) = \displaystyle{\frac{c}{a}}$ \hspace{4cm}  $cos (\beta) = \displaystyle{\frac{b}{a}}$
\end{center}
\begin{center}
$tg (\alpha) = \displaystyle{\frac{b}{c}}$ \hspace{4cm}  $cos (\beta) = \displaystyle{\frac{c}{b}}$
\end{center}
    \end{minipage}
    };
%%digite o subtitulo aqui.
\node[subtitulo,minimum width=\largura] at (box4.north) {\tituloA{Conclus\~ao}};
%%Quinta caixa
\begingroup
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{}
\node[mybox] (box5) [below = of box4.south west,anchor=north west] {
    \begin{minipage}[t][17cm]{\largura}
      Área e Comprimento da Circunferência:\\
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
%\includegraphics[scale=1.7]{abc.png}
\end{figure} 
$$C = 2\cdot \pi \cdot R$$
$$A = \pi \cdot R^2$$
    \end{minipage}
    };
%%digite o subtitulo aqui.
\node[subtitulo,minimum width=\largura] at (box5.north) {\tituloA{Refer\^encias}};
\endgroup
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe, part 1]

The content of the `mal-poster-extraction.tex` file is this:

```
%! *latex mal-poster-extraction.tex
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
% I measured rectangles roughly in PS_View...
\foreach \xm/\ym/\xmax/\ymax in {
33.4/46.8/3/23,
33.4/46.8/62/23,
33.4/46.8/4.4/69,
33.4/46.8/62.2/68.7,
4.4/69/33/96,
62.2/68.7/33/96,
62.2/68.7/90/97} {%
  %\xm, \ym, \xmax, \ymax\par % list the coordinates
  \newpage
  \includegraphics[viewport=\xm cm \ym cm \xmax cm \ymax cm, clip, scale=0.1]{mal-poster.pdf}%
  }% End of \foreach statement...
\end{document}
```

This is a preview of the `mal-poster-extraction-crop.pdf` file:

[image: mwe, part 2]